# change the array principal to get role based instead of Service account based

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-iam

I need to change a code to work with IAM conditions:

Today our code has a variable that has multiple principals and each principal has one or more roles in the format as describe in the inline code variable orig.

Because now we want to enable iam conditions, the inline code does not account for conditions. The inline code changes the array to be roles and a list of principals assocaited with that role since we use the iam_binding. This wipes any previously assign role and just the one in the code gets applied.

```
locals {
  orig = {
    # All GCP Users
    "group:grp1@mydomain.com" = [
      "roles/logging.configWriter"
    ]
    "serviceAccount:my-service-account@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com" = [    
      "roles/logging.configWriter",
      "roles/run.admin"
    ]
  }

  orig_all_roles = distinct(flatten(values(local.orig)))
  orig_bindings_IAM = {
    for role in local.orig_all_roles : role => [
      for group, groupRole in local.orig : group if try(index(groupRole, role), null) != null
    ]
  }

resource "google_organization_iam_binding" "org" {
  for_each = local.orig_bindings_IAM
  org_id   = var.organization_id
  role     = each.key
  members  = each.value
}
}
```

Because we I need to use conditions now for certain roles and teams I'm trying to change this in order to accommodate the condition section, the inline code generates a list but I have not been able to apply to the iam_binding so far.

```
locals {
  new = {
    # All GCP Users
    "group:grp1@mydomain.com" = [
      { 
          role = "roles/logging.configWriter"
          condition = { 
            title: "my title"
            description: "my description", 
            expression: "condition"
      }
    }
    ]    
    
    "serviceAccount:my-service-account@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com" = [
      {
        role: "roles/logging.configWriter"
        condition: null
      },
      {
        role: "roles/run.admin"
        condition: null
      }
    ]
  }

  new_all_roles2 = flatten([
    for r, roles in local.new : [
      for x in roles : {
        role      = x.role
        member    = r
        condition = x.condition
      }
    ]
  ])

  just_roles = distinct([for role in local.new_all_roles2 : role.role])

  roles_grouped = {
    for role_obj in local.new_all_roles2 :
    role_obj.role => [
      for obj in local.new_all_roles2 :
      {
        member    = obj.member
        condition = obj.condition
      }
      if obj.role == role_obj.role
    ]...
  }

  roles_grouped_unique = {
    for key, values_list in local.roles_grouped : key => (distinct([for sublist in values_list : sublist]))
  }
}
```

I'm pretty much stuck in the new_binding_IAM. What I envison to apply would be along the lines of this code

```
resource "google_organization_iam_binding" "org" {
  for_each = local.new_bindings_IAM
  org_id   = var.organization_id
  role     = each.key
  members  = each.value.member
  condition {
     title =each.value.condition.title
     description = each.value.condition.description
     expression =each.value.condition.expression
   }
}
```

Any ideas on how I could get the right output for new_bindings_IAM?

**Update 1**: Hopefully added clarity and updated the code to reflect the current status of my tries.

Comment: Your question is interesting and I am interested in the answer. However, invest some time into the problem description as I had to read it several times to understand what you are asking. My guess is that this post will be closed for lack of clarity. Refer to this [guide](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/) to help you.

Comment: thanks, I've updated the question and hopefully it provides more clarity.